# MySQL remove duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a comments table, whose structure is as:

```
id, name, email, comment
```

I have many duplicate comments, with same name and email. I need to remove them, can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this using a single query?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicate Rows Leaving Oldest Row Only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671607/remove-duplicate-rows-leaving-oldest-row-only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM comments c1 

WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM comments c2 
    WHERE c2.id <> c1.id 
        AND c2.name = c1.name 
        AND c2.email = c1.email 
        AND c2.comment = c1.comment
)

AND c1.id <> (
    SELECT MIN(c2.id) 
    FROM comments c2 
    WHERE c2.name = c1.name 
        AND c2.email = c1.email 
        AND c2.comment = c1.comment
)
```