# SQL Remove Row That Has The Same Values Into New Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Duplicate Rows Leaving Oldest Row Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671607/remove-duplicate-rows-leaving-oldest-row-only)
>   [MySQL remove duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712809/mysql-remove-duplicate-rows)

Say that I have the following table coolumns: **int logicalid(pk) ,int home, int person**  say the I have the following records...
1,5,6
2,5,6
3,5,5
4,5,5

After my query, I want to place into the new table only one row with the same home,person column values so this will be the output result:
1,5,6
2,5,5
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Create your new table with an auto-increment column for the id.

Then insert into the table, using a query such as:

```
insert into newTable(home, person)
    select distinct home, person
    from oldTable
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO newtable(home, person) SELECT DISTINCT home, person FROM sourcetable`