# SQL: select all records not selected by another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for an SQL query to select all records not selected by another query on the same table. 
Specifically I want to select all records which have duplicates of a particular field('fieldA') and then delete all but one of those records.

So a select statement might be something like the following (which doesn't work!):

```
select * from table where id not in(select * from table group by fieldA)
```

If a single query is not possible then what would be the most efficient solution?

Comment: Change the * to `id` in the inner SELECT statement... does that not work?

Comment: I did try this already but phpMyAdmin crashes.

Comment: What's the criteria for which row remains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically I want to select all records which have duplicates of a particular field('fieldA') and then delete all but one of those records.

In that case, [join it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671607/remove-duplicate-rows-leaving-oldest-row-only):

```
delete x 
from myTable x
 join myTable z on x.field = z.field
where x.id > z.id
```

Comment: +1 nice, no aggregates! You should add to answer that this keeps the `MIN(ID)` if you want `MAX(ID)` then you just reverse the direction to `x.id < z.id`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. This answer is brilliant, exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM table GROUP BY fieldA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your not IN sub SELECT statement to only return one column (ID), it should work -

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/