# MySQL Delete with Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am running a query successfully using in MySQL 5.5

```
SELECT columnA
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  columnA
HAVING
  count(*) > 1
```

However, I need to run this same query using DELETE and I'm a little unsure how to delete ? i.e. the returned results should be deleted ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Place it in a subquery:

```
delete from table 
where columnA in (
  select columnA
  from (
      select columnA
      from YourTable
      group by columnA
      having count(*) > 1
      ) t  
)
```

Comment: @Dennis - thanks for the help :) I'm getting "You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause" ? Using MySQL 5.5 ?

Comment: Oh, right. I always forget about MySQL's gotchas. :-) Subgroup it a second time to force it use a temp table: `delete from table where colA in (select colA from ([your thing]) t)`

Comment: @Dennis - ah :) that's what was getting me! Thanks a heap - you might want to update your answer :)

Comment: @Dennis - I think this actually deletes every row ?

Comment: As I read it, it should delete any row with a matching columnA value. In other words, all rows where columnA has a value which exists more than once in the table.

Comment: yeah that's right in theory ... but when I run it - it deletes ALL data in columnA ?

Comment: Yes, it deletes all matching records. If you're seeking to remove duplicates and keep a single one, you should be [doing this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205640/sql-select-all-records-not-selected-by-another-query/6206575#6206575).

Comment: @Dennis - but it only should delete matching records where the count(*) > 1 ? [that is, if there are 2 records - it will delete 1 and keep the other?] I don't understand why it deletes everything instead ?

Comment: "that is, if there are 2 records - it will delete 1 and keep the other" -- no, your query is written so that it will delete both. See my last comment's link for a means to keep the first one.

Comment: so I have to put this inside the select ? delete from table 
where columnA in (
  select columnA
  from ( ) ?

Comment: @Tom: if you want to only eliminate dups, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205640/sql-select-all-records-not-selected-by-another-query/6206575#6206575

Comment: May i know why it needs an extra select query, but cannot just run with:

delete from table 
where columnA in (
      select columnA
      from YourTable
      group by columnA
      having count(*) > 1
)

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from YourTable
where
  YourTable.columnA 
  in 
  (select columnA
  from
    YourTable
  group by
    column A
  having
    count(*) > 1)
```