# How to delete child records which is having count more than ten for a parent and I should retain parent record phoenix sql

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

I have a parent and child information in same table now I have to delete the child records which is having count more than ten for a single parent.

I was able to get count of child for each parent but I was not able delete only the child records having count more than ten for a parent and I should retain  parent record and only delete child records

```
select parent,count(child) from table group by parent having count(child >10);
```

It gives results:

```
Parent. |  Count(child)

1053.   |    15
3052.   |    30
3467.   |    45
```

Now I have to delete only the count of child records more than 10 and I tried different ways but didn't help me.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `delete from table where parent in (Select parent from (Select parent,count(child) from table group by parent having count(child)>10))` check if this works

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296102/mysql-delete-with-group-by

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE TABLE SET CHILD =NULL WHERE PARENT IN (SELECT 
  PARENT FROM(SELECT 
  PARENT,COUNT(CHILD) FROM TABLE GROUP BY 
  PARENT HAVING COUNT(CHILD)>10));
```

> This will first get the parent with count as greater than 10 then delete that parent child records from the table

Comment: Here want to retain parent records and I only have delete the child records.but as you mentioned above it is deleting child and as well parent.but I want only to delete child records.

Comment: you cant delete seperately column records here in case  child as it is dependent on parent record just like how can you delete one column record in a row where other columns records are there for instance parent(1),child(1) how can you delete child only for that you need to delete full row or you can update that record

Comment: Create a trigger/procedure to do some operation on some value or your requirement