# In SQL, how can I create a query that shows all the elements of a table that are in one set and not in another?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access, and I have a table of forms that people submit.  I need to find all of the people who submitted forms in one month but not another.  More specifically, I need to find all of the forms that are in a set where they match `A` in a `type` field, `June` in a `month` field, and `August` in a `processed` field **which are not in** a set where they match `B` in the `type` field and `August` in the `month` field.

Many people are supposed to submit additional forms in a later month, and I'm trying to find who hasn't done that.

I found this question: [SQL: select all records not selected by another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205640/sql-select-all-records-not-selected-by-another-query).  It seems similar, but I'm not really looking for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT PersonID FROM FormsSubmitted
WHERE 
    [type]="A" 
    AND 
    [month]="June"
    AND
    PersonID NOT IN (
        SELECT PersonID FROM FormsSubmitted
        WHERE [type]="B" AND [month]="August"
    )
```

Notes:

- This answer makes a few assumptions, but I hope it gives you an idea on how to proceed.
- One of those assumptions is that the [month] field is stored as text. If so, then that is almost always a *Bad Idea™*. If that is the case and it is practical for you to change the [month] field to a number, then you should seriously consider doing so.

Comment: That syntax is just what I needed.  Thank you.  The month field is text, and I wish it was a number, but I don't have the authority to change any types.