# How to delete a table row if the field "post_title" is duplicated in another row?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Duplicate Rows Leaving Oldest Row Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671607/remove-duplicate-rows-leaving-oldest-row-only)

I have a `posts_table` in my DB..
That posts_table have the fields `post_title`, `post_id`, (and some others that dont matter).

I need to delete one of the rows if the post_title repeats in another row.

Example:

```
posts_table
-------------------------------------------
post_id  | post_title
-------------------------------------------
501      |  Some post title here  
502      |  Another post title
503      |  A test post tile
504      |  Some post title here  (this is duplicated, i need to delete this row)
505      |  A different post title
```

With the sentence below i can check all duplicated post_titles

```
SELECT    post_title, COUNT(post_title) AS dup_count
FROM      posts_table
GROUP BY  post_title
HAVING    (COUNT(post_title) > 1)
```

The question is, How can i delete all rows with duplicated post_titles??

The best and fastest query for this is:

```
delete from posts_table where post_id in (
  select post_id from (
    select post_id from posts_table a group by post_title having count(post_title) > 1
  ) b
)
```

Comment: Do you really want to delete all of them, or all except one? If so, which one do you leave?

Comment: Also I doubt if your SQL will work as you are mixing aggregated and non-aggregated output.

Comment: I need to delete ONE of the rows that repeats and left the other intact, dont matter wich one will be deleted. And i dont know what you mean "your sql" but that sentence properly retrieving the post_title and how many times it was found.

Comment: @Lucas Yes the SQL looks ok now you have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
DELETE FROM Posts_Table 
WHERE Post_ID NOT IN    
    (
     SELECT a.Post_ID
     FROM
        (
         SELECT Post_Title, Post_ID 
         FROM Posts_Table 
         GROUP BY Post_Title
         ) a
    )
```

Comment: Yuk! It deleted everything in my table... Not working...

Comment: @huelbois oh typo error i forget to put `NOT` and `GROUP BY` clause in the query, try it again.

Comment: OK, it works now. Dangerous typo !

Comment: @huelbois sorry for the first query.

Comment: Well, it was only crap in my table, created it only to try to answer! Reversed my vote.

Comment: johntotetwoo, thank you, its working. So is this sentence too heavy for the server? is possible to execute it everytime a new post is made? im talking about like 100+ posts a day.

Comment: `DELETE FROM hotaru_posts
WHERE post_id NOT IN    
    (
     SELECT a.post_id
     FROM
        (
         SELECT post_title, post_id
         FROM hotaru_posts
         GROUP BY post_title
         ) a
    )`

Comment: `SELECT    post_title, COUNT(post_title) AS dup_count
FROM      hotaru_posts
GROUP BY  post_title
HAVING    (COUNT(post_title) > 1) `