# How can i make this heavy SQL query lighter?

Tags: mysql

Sometimes i use this sql query to remove duplicated posts from my posts table.
But its takes a long time to finish, letting my domain unaccessible for like 5 minutes.
Look like this is a heavy sql for the server, theres a way to make it lighter and faster?

```
DELETE FROM hotaru_posts WHERE post_id NOT IN ( SELECT a.post_id FROM ( SELECT post_title, post_id FROM hotaru_posts GROUP BY post_title ) a )
```

The optimal and fastest query for this is

```
delete from hotaru_posts where post_id in (
  select post_id from (
    select post_id from hotaru_posts a group by post_title having count(post_title) > 1
  ) b
)
```

This query took only 0.0603 sec. while the fisrt query took more than 5 min. (lol)

Comment: Does the current one work? It shouldn't: you are selecting a non-aggregated `post_id` in a `GROUP BY post_title`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yeah, but, IIRC, MySQL will just pick an undetermined value from the group in this case.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In other words, this statement deletes random duplicates :)

Comment: well it works, i got this query here on stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196884/how-to-delete-a-table-row-if-the-field-post-title-is-duplicated-in-another-row

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: More specifically, from all duplicates of a post it deletes all but one. Which post survives is up to the destiny :)

Comment: @sergio, yes, thats exactly what you just said, but dont matter what post will stay, i need only one, wich one doesnt matter, so thats work for my needs. I just need to make it faster.

Comment: You might want to look more carefully into how and why you have such a problem in the first place.  What is the cause of all of this duplicated data and is there a reason you aren't using a unique key to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal and fastest query for this is

```
delete from hotaru_posts where post_id in (
  select post_id from (
    select post_id from hotaru_posts a group by post_title having count(post_title) > 1
  ) b
)
```

This query took only 0.0603 sec. while the fisrt query took more than 5 min. (lol)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
DELETE FROM hotaru_posts
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(post_id)
        FROM hotaru_posts a
        GROUP BY post_title
        HAVING COUNT(post_title) > 1
    ) b
)
```

Comment: would this work?? you tell me, im afraid to test it cause this is my live website.

Comment: @LucasMatos: copy it and test. Not having a copy of your data is a baaad thing.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE testTable AS SELECT * FROM hotaru_posts` - that will duplicate your table and name it 'testTable' try running this query on that table.

Comment: It does include one less `SELECT` and if it works as I think it will, the new `SELECT` will only retrieve the duplicates instead of everything that's not a duplicate. So yes, I _think_ it will be faster.

Comment: @Travesty3: Error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'testTable' for update in FROM clause
`DELETE FROM testTable WHERE post_id IN (
SELECT MAX( post_id )
FROM testTable
GROUP BY post_title
HAVING COUNT( post_title ) >1
)`

Comment: almost that @Travesty3, check the first post.

Comment: @LucasMatos: Ah, so you still needed the double `SELECT` to get around the whole 'updating and selecting from the same table at the same time' issue. Looks like it was much faster to select just the duplicates instead of the non-duplicates, though. Glad to hear it helped. I will update my answer for anyone else that stumbles upon this post as well.